# Copy RDLC report text and paste in notepad

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I have a reportviewer in windows form application which is showing RDLC report. I need to copy a text of that report and save it in notepad. Can anybody help?
[image]

e.g I need to copy the text "LiFTER ASSY"  only, but without exporting directly from reportviewer itself.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What text you to copy?

Comment: I mean that, I cannot highlight and copy a text shown in RDLC report (in report viewer). I need to highlight and copy selected text in that report using my mouse.

Comment: I am afraid that there's no way the copy the text with you requirments. Either you must have access to the data (you're the developer) or you must export the report.

Comment: is this an X/Y problem? Why do you need to copy an already rendered export?

Comment: Its not X/Y problem. I just need to copy the text from report.. The report shows thousands of rows of data.. I have to copy specific texts for some personal use.

Comment: why don't you extract the query from the RDLC, execute it against the database and extract the value you need?

Comment: Hi @Ahmedilyas , My requirement is not about querying again. Please understand my requirement clearly.   :)

Comment: understood and hence my comment.... you CAN do what you want but will involve another query.

Answer (score 2):

You either export or copy it yourself by typing. It's read-only the generated report.

Answer (score 1):

You can export the report to pdf, excel or word. From there you can try to copy the text.

Comment: That's not a solution in my context. Exporting is not solution, but I need to copy only specific words form the report. eg. "Nation" from entire essay about nation. And I think that exporting the report might not be an efficient solution. Its faster rather typing. Therefore I need to copy specific texts.

Comment: When you export the report its the same like you see it in rendered in the application. If you export it in excel, you can copy the cell content for example

Comment: I have already understood what you mean, but please,, that is not a solution for me. I hope my question is clear to you.

Comment: Can you please provide screenshot of the report.

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2005 I've been waiting for this feature!**

The only workarround I've ever found is to use the Hyperlink event from ReporViewer in order to emulate the copy action (based on http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/30424/0/page/6).

In the report, set an hiperlink like:

```
="copy:" & Fields!SomeField.Value
```

And then in the code:

```
private void reportViewer_Hyperlink(object sender, HyperlinkEventArgs e)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(e.Hyperlink);
    if (uri.Scheme.ToLower() == "copy")
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(uri.Authority);
        e.Cancel = true; // Load the customer details in another form
        ((ReportViewer)sender).RefreshReport();
    }
 }
```